# R: changing x-axis tick mark labels in forestplot

Tags: r, visualization, r-forestplot

```
library(forestplot)
# Cochrane data from the 'rmeta'-package
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
    upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 0.731)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
    "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
    "Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
  c("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", 
    "4", "14", "3", "1", 
    "8", NA, NA),
  c("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", 
    "11", "20", "7", "7", 
    "10", NA, NA),
  c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
    "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
    "1.02", NA, "0.53"))

forestplot(tabletext, 
           cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
           is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
           clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
           xlog=TRUE, 
           col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

[image]

I have a forestplot, and my x-axis tick mark labels are spaced a bit strangely, and I would like to change it to having each tick mark be 0.1 apart from each other. Also, does anyone know how forestplot decides how the ticks are spaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `forestplot` documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html#ticks-and-grids), you have two options.

1. you can set manually in your `forestplot()` expression your ticks, e.g. `xticks = c(-.1, -0.05, 0, .05)`
2. you can create a sequence, e.g. `xticks <- seq(from = -0.08, to = 2.50, by = 0.1)` and add it to your `forestplot()` expression with `xticks = xticks`